# Empty table error when trying to build chart

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I wrote a script at Google Apps Script to generate test result reports in PDF format that appear in a spreadsheet. Apparently the script is correct, but it's obviously not, since every time it returns the error

> "Exception: Cannot create a chart with an empty data table."

Does anyone have a suggestion on what to do?

The script is below, and I also included a print of part of the data in the spreadsheet.

```
// Constants that store specific Google Drive files and folder IDs
const DOCID = '1cfVmsXj1rtmWEM3NL28oTiDPsGjxQelv8aHoqkw4brw'; // The ID of the Google Document template
const FOLDERID = '1NqdCopDxoyANKcmfkXJCnh4pE6AvNNN5'; // The ID of the target Google Drive folder

// This function runs every time the Google Sheet is opened
function onOpen() {
    // Get the UI of the Google Sheet and add menu items
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
        .createMenu('Test result reports')
        .addItem('Generate reports', 'generateReports')
        .addItem('Send reports', 'sendReports')
        .addToUi();
}

// Helper function to validate email addresses
function isValidEmail(email) {
    const regex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}

// FUNCTION THAT GENERATES THE TEST REPORTS
function generateReports() {

    const activeSpreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(); // Get the active spreadsheet's ID dynamically
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(activeSpreadsheetId).getSheetByName('Envio de report');
    const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    const temp = DriveApp.getFileById(DOCID);
    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDERID);
    const rows = data.slice(1); // Skip the headers row
    const skillNames = ["Objetividade Argumentativa", "Análise sob Incerteza", "Análise de Padrões", "Inteligência Espacial", "Pensamento Matemático", "Total Cognitivo", "Inglês"]; // Skill names array

    rows.forEach((row, index) => {
        const email = row[2];

        // Check if report hasn't been generated yet (column AR in the row must be empty)
        if (row[43] == '') {
            const file = temp.makeCopy(folder);
            const doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
            const body = doc.getBody();

            // Loop through the spreadsheet header row to replace placeholders in the document body
            data[0].forEach((heading, i) => {
                body.replaceText(`{${heading}}`, row[i]);
            });

            // Replace placeholders in the document header
            const headers = doc.getHeader();
            if (headers) {
                data[0].forEach((heading, i) => {
                    headers.replaceText(`{${heading}}`, row[i]);
                });
            }

            // Generate chart comparing candidate's score, top quintile average, and median score
            const candidateScoresIndices = [4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22];
            const topQuintileIndices = candidateScoresIndices.map(index => index + 1);
            const medianIndices = candidateScoresIndices.map(index => index + 2);

            // Log the row values to debug
            Logger.log('Row values: ' + row);
            Logger.log('Candidate Scores: ' + candidateScoresIndices.map(i => row[i]));
            Logger.log('Top Quintile: ' + topQuintileIndices.map(i => row[i]));
            Logger.log('Median: ' + medianIndices.map(i => row[i]));

            const dataTable = Charts.newDataTable()
                .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, 'Habilidade')
                .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Nota')
                .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Top Quintile')
                .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Mediana')
                .build();

            // Use the provided skill names and format the scores
            for(let i = 0; i < candidateScoresIndices.length; i++) {
                dataTable.addRow([skillNames[i], formatAsPercentage(row[candidateScoresIndices[i]]), formatAsPercentage(row[topQuintileIndices[i]]), formatAsPercentage(row[medianIndices[i]])]);
            }

            const chartBuilder = Charts.newComboChart()
                .setDataTable(dataTable)
                .setDimensions(600, 400)
                .setRange(0, 1)
                .setSeries([{
                    type: Charts.ChartType.BARS,
                    targetAxisIndex: 0,
                    color: '#7B70AD'
                }, {
                    type: Charts.ChartType.LINE,
                    targetAxisIndex: 0,
                    color: '#B46AAB'
                }, {
                    type: Charts.ChartType.STEPPED_AREA,
                    targetAxisIndex: 0,
                    color: '#D8D5E7'
                }])
                .setLegendPosition(Charts.Position.BOTTOM);

            const chart = chartBuilder.build();

            // Insert the chart where bookmark named 'CHART_POSITION' is
            const bookmark = doc.getBookmarkById('CHART_POSITION');
            const position = bookmark.getPosition();
            body.insertImage(position, chart.getAs('image/png')).setAltDescription('Resultado por habilidade').setWidth(600).setHeight(400);

            // Set the name of the new document based on the user name
            doc.setName('Relatório individual - ' + row[1]);

            // Convert doc to PDF
            const blob = doc.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
            doc.saveAndClose();

            // Save the PDF in the specified folder and set its name
            folder.createFile(blob).setName('[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imgl6.png)Relatório individual - ' + row[1] + '.pdf');

            // Set the report creation date in column U for the current row
            const creationDateCell = sheet.getRange(index + 2, 21); // +2 because arrays are 0-indexed and we skipped the header row
            const formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
            creationDateCell.setValue(formattedDate);
        }
    });
}

// Helper function to format values as percentages
function formatAsPercentage(value) {
    return (value * 100).toFixed(0) + '%';
}
```

Comment: Which line throws the error? Have you confirmed that the script you posted now, after modifications throws the same error?

Comment: Try not building your dataTable until after you add the rows.

Comment: I first tested with a Scatter Chart and then wanted to see if it worked with Combo Chart but get the error `Charts.newComboChart is not a function`.  I think it is only available through `google.visualization`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of building a Scatter Chart.  As I noted `newComboChart` is not a method of `Charts`.  I have also noticed that most methods of `ScatterChartBuilder` and `DataTableBuilder` return `this` so you don't need to chain methods.

**Code.gs**

```
function drawChart() {
  let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Scatter");
  let data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  let header = data.shift();

  let dataTable = Charts.newDataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER,header[0]);
  dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER,header[1]);
  dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER,header[2]);

  data.forEach( row => dataTable.addRow(row) );
  dataTable = dataTable.build();

  let chart = Charts.newScatterChart()
                .setDataTable(dataTable)
                .build();

  let doc = DocumentApp.create("TestChart");
  let body = doc.getBody();
  body.appendImage(chart.getBlob());
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Reference**

- [ScatterCharBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/scatter-chart-builder)
- [DataTableBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-table-builder)